# Read files based on dates in their names in Python

Tags: python, regex, file, date, input

I am new to Python. I have files with filenames containing date and hour like wordcount-12012013-0.txt , wordcount-12012013-1.txt ..... wordcount-12012013-24.txt - so these files are for every hour of december 1st,2013 and I have such file for 30 days. I need to find daily word count that is pick all 24 hour files for a particular day and print word count for that day and continue this for all 30 day files. Any help on how to do this ?

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us what you've already tried.

Comment: please read http://sscce.org about how to ask a question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply loop through all the files, f.e. constructing the filenames in your code. e.g. for the current day you could do that, in this format via:

```
import datetime
'wordcount-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y-%H") + '.txt'
```

this would give 'wordcount-02012014-03.txt' executed now in this hour so you should apply this approach to your historical dates. should you wish to combine file names with pathnames, you could use

```
import os
os.path.join()
```

then loop through all the files. hope this helps, good luck